# Lets choose the Logo

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, beta

What logo do we need to use this site when it public?

There maybe couple of variations [Buddhist symbolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_symbolism)

- The most famous one is [Dharmacakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmacakra)
- Other famouse one is [Ashoka Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashoka_Chakra)
- In the other hand we have [Buddhist Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_flag)

Please read these resource as well,

- http://people.opposingviews.com/buddhist-religious-symbol-called-6703.html
- http://buddhism.about.com/od/eightauspicioussymbols/a/The-Dharma-Wheel.htm

lets choose what is the best symbol for the site logo. Any comments are really appreciate.

Comment: FYI - and this is not meant as discouragement - the site will not get a real logo until it graduates, and that's almost guaranteed to be at least a year away. There's no harm in talking about elements of site design right now, but it probably won't help all that much either.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @senshin I hope we can make the site get graduated

Answer (score 5):

The Logo should be [Dharmacakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmacakra)

CC Image here
[https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dharma_Wheel.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aDharma_Wheel.svg)

Answer (score 1):

We have quite a bit of time before we reach the point where we need a logo. It's probably best to not focus on it now and focus more about getting quality content which would attract people!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a draft logo I made some time ago for [our internal Q&A site](http://ask.sirimangalo.org/):

[image: Q&A Logo]

It was received with mixed reviews; some people thought it disrespectful to put the Buddha behind the bar in the A.

Comment: I agree that Buddha looks awkward behind that A. I like the left side though, it would make a nice logo by itself!

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid my suggestion may look controversial, but let me still post it. Feel free to downvote if it's bad.

**We have to negotiate with our friends in [Hinduism Beta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) site.**

Here's why.

As other answers say, the most famous/recognizable symbols of Buddhism are **Dharmachakra** and **Asoka Chakra**. I would also add **Aum** here.

[image: Aum]

All these symbols are *also* most recognizable for Hinduism. Moreover, Dharmachakra presents in National Flag of India.

[image: National Flag of India]

So it is well possible that they will want Dharmachakra, in this case **Aum** will be best for us.

Hence, my idea is not to interfere with them, but **collaborate** and mutually figure out what's best for both Betas.

Edit: [Related discussion at Meta.Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like)

Comment: Devanagari AUM is more Hindustic than Buddhist.

Comment: Agree with catnopsis - "aum" would not make for a good logo for this site, since it is far more strongly associated with Hinduism than Buddhism (at least by the people who will be reading this site, i.e. English speakers, who are mostly Americans).